# Design Choice - MDI with tab control or tab pages with controls?

Tags: c#, tabs, mdi

I'm in the process of building a little application to edit some specific text files. I want to have a tabbed interface so I can switch between documents quickly. The way I see it is I have two choices.

A) I use a normal tab control and have it fill the entire form. Then each tab page that gets created with have a textbox to hold the document text. Possibly by creating my own custom tab pages with a textbox and other controls I feel are necessary.

B) I make my form an MDI container and use a tab control to switch between the forms. (Linking the tab pages with a corresponding MDI child form)

I feel option A would be a bit easier to do. However, I wanted to get your thoughts on which option I should pursue.

Please let me know your thoughts! Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I can´t see any major advantages between two choices. Using tabs directly will be more easier switching between the documents and data manipulation between them.

Comment: Just a suggestion, please everyone don't crucify me for this: This looks like an excellent opportunity to learn some XAML and get up-to-date with desktop technologies < 10 years old (you may choose between WPF and WinRT).